# How do I prove that this set is a Borel set?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I have the following Problem:

> Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Borel-mesurable functions. Show that $\{x|\limsup\,f_n(x)=\infty\}$ is  borel set.

In the lecture, we did a similar proof with $\lim f_n(x)$ instead of $\limsup$. There we rewrote the condition in terms of quantors (i.e., with $\forall, \exists$) and then interpreted this as unions and intersections. But somehow, I don't see it here. Could maybe someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: `\limsup f_n(x)`, `\lim f_n(x)`

Comment: Your approach sounds right. Are you having trouble expanding the definition of $\limsup$ to rewrite the condition $\limsup f_n(x)=\infty$ using quantifiers?

Comment: One way to start is to show that $g_n = \sup_{k \ge n} f_k$ is Borel-measurable.  Then apply the result from your lecture to $\lim g_n$.

Comment: yes I somehow have troubles to rewrite this with quantifiers.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1327089/591889

Comment: @UmbertoP. If I want to do it in your way, is it correct that I also rewrite sup with quantifiers?

Comment: If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence, then $\sup_n a_n > t$ if and only if there exists at least one index with $a_n > t$.  Thus $$\{ x \mid g_n(x) > t\} = \cup_{k=n}^\infty \{x \mid f_k(x) > t\}$$ and these are all Borel sets.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Your way sounds interesting, but why do I don't care about $\infty$ so in the exercise the limes superior is $\infty$

Comment: First, try rewriting $\limsup$ using the definition of $\limsup$. Then, try changing the definition so that the quantifiers range only over a countable set rather than all of $\mathbb{R}$. From here, turn these quantifiers over countable sets into intersections and unions.

Comment: @MarkSaving. Yes this was just my idea but I don't manage it to do it with lim sup, somehow I'm confused. Could you maybe help me more because the link from above wasn't very helpful