# The derivative (defined a.e.) is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define $g:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
g(x) :=
\begin{cases}
f^{\prime}(x) & \text{if } f \text { Fréchet differentiable at } x, \\
0 & \text {otherwise }.
\end{cases}
\quad \forall x \in (a, b),
$$
and $g(a)=g(b)=0$.

I'm trying to make sense of integrating the derivative (defined a.e.) by proving below result.

> **Theorem** If $f$ is Borel measurable, then so is $g$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** Let $D := \{x \in (a, b) : f \text{ Fréchet differentiable at }x \}$. Then $D$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$. This can be proved by extending $f$ to the whole $\mathbb R$ (for example, we set $f$ to be $0$ outside $[a, b]$), and then applying *Section 3.5* of the book *Fréchet Differentiability of Lipschitz Functions and Porous Sets in Banach Spaces* by Lindenstrauss/Preiss/Tišer, i.e.,

> *"In this short section we show that for an arbitrary map between Banach spaces the set of its points of Fréchet differentiability is Borel; in fact it has type $F_{\sigma \delta}$*.

Let
$$
g_n(x) :=
\begin{cases}
\frac{f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}} & \text{if } x \in D, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\quad \forall n\in \mathbb N, x \in [a, b].
$$

It follows from $f$ and $D$ are Borel measurable that $g_n$ is Borel measurable. Moreover, $g_n \to g$ everywhere. The everywhere limit of a sequence of Borel measurable functions [is again Borel measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4560364/hausdorff-topological-spaces-is-the-pointwise-limit-of-a-sequence-of-borel-meas?noredirect=1&lq=1). So $g$ is Borel measurable. This completes the proof.

Comment: Why is $D$ Borel measurable? (I know it is but you don't give an argument for that)

Comment: @OliverDíaz I have just found a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105810/continuous-functions-are-differentiable-on-a-measurable-set).

Comment: that proof is for $f$ continuous. For general $f$ (measurable or not) things are more subtle.

Comment: @OliverDíaz It seems [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105822/1019043) of the answer works for Borel measurable function.

Comment: Oh! I didn't not see that solution. The is a little problem which is easy to fix: $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ may not be defined, so to extend $f$ (defined on $(a,b)$) one can choose to set $f=0$ outside $(a, b)$ (after all one is only interesting in points in $(a, b)$.