# Does the subdifferential of a convex function admit a measurable selection?

Tags: convex-analysis, optimal-transport

For a convex function $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},$ the subdifferential is defined as
$$\partial \varphi (x) = \{z \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \varphi(y) \geq \varphi(x) + \langle z, y - x\rangle\}.$$
My question is **under what conditions there exists a measurable function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x) \in \partial \varphi(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$**
I am aware of Kuratowski and Ryll-Nardzewski measurable selection theorem, but I am not sure how to apply this to the subdifferential correspondence.
Any reference will be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: By "measurable function", do you mean Borel or Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: I originally meant the Borel measurability, but I'm also interested in the Lebesgue one if this difference affects the result!

Comment: Because convex function on $\mathbb R^d$ is differentiable a.e. and the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is complete, such Lebesgue measurable selection exists.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436895/optimal-transport-how-is-this-transport-map-borel-measurable) question may be of your interest.

Comment: Also, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4607083/368425) question...

Comment: @Akira Thank you for your comments! I don't get the point perfectly yet. I understand that the set of non-differentiable points is Lebesgue measurable and has zero measure. But values on the set matters for the measurabilty of the selection, right? How should I select values from the subdifferential on non-differentiable points to make the selection Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Please see my below answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be the set on which $\varphi$ is Fréchet differentiable. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607083/the-derivative-defined-a-e-is-borel-measurable) thread, $D$ is a Borel set. On the other hand, convex functions on $\mathbb R^n$ is differentiable a.e., so $D^c := \mathbb R^n \setminus D$ is a Lebesgue null set. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607083/the-derivative-defined-a-e-is-borel-measurable) thread, the restriction $\nabla \varphi:D \to \mathbb R^n$ is Borel measurable. We define $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ as follows:

- If $x \in D$ then $f(x) := \nabla \varphi (x)$.
- If $x \notin D$ then we pick any $y \in \partial f(x)$ and let $f(x) := y$.

Because the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is complete, a subset of a Lebesgue null set is Lebesgue measurable. This implies *arbitrary* modification of a Lebesgue measurable function on a  Lebesgue null set remains Lebesgue measurable. Hence $f$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Why are you talking about Fréchet differentiability in finite dimension? What does it add by using this level of abstraction?

Comment: @mordecaiiwazuki The usual derivative in finite dimensions is also Fréchet derivative. I explicitly use the term "Fréchet" because the quoted theorem in the book uses it. I don't think using the term "Fréchet" appeals to any high level of abstraction.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer that I got a downvote?

Comment: Well, behold, lot's of people here and MO get triggered for all kinds of reasons. It might be the Frechet / over-abstraction thing, it could just be due to not enough sunlight, anything really. Anyways, I've upvoted the answer because it fits the bill perfectly (and I learned something new).

Comment: @dohmatob Thank you so much for your supportive comment :)

Comment: @Akira Thanks! This makes sense! Please let me know if you have something you can say about the Borel case.

Comment: I'm also curious by the same question, so I have just posted [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453940/is-there-a-borel-measurable-f-mathbbrd-to-mathbbrd-such-that-fx-i) on MO...